# Is there a better way to reverse an array of bytes in memory?

Tags: c++, memory, swap, std

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

...

void ReverseBytes( void *start, int size )
{
    Byte *buffer = (Byte *)(start);

    for( int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++ ) {
        std::swap( buffer[i], buffer[size - i - 1] );
    }
}
```

What this method does right now is it reverses bytes in memory. What I would like to know is, is there a better way to get the same effect? The whole "size / 2" part seems like a bad thing, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: I just realized how bad the title I put for this question was, so I [hopefully] fixed it.

Comment: Your example seems flawed, how can you swap two chars without a location?  I suspect you need pass in the address.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The standard library has a [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function:

```
#include <algorithm>
void ReverseBytes( void *start, int size )
{
    char *istart = start, *iend = istart + size;
    std::reverse(istart, iend);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked it up before writing it myself.

Comment: The description of the reverse function states that it is implemented exactly the way the person who asked the question implemented it and that it has the same complexity. It's not really a better way. A cleaner way maybe at best..

Answer (score 27):

A performant solution without using the STL:

```
void reverseBytes(void *start, int size) {
    unsigned char *lo = start;
    unsigned char *hi = start + size - 1;
    unsigned char swap;
    while (lo < hi) {
        swap = *lo;
        *lo++ = *hi;
        *hi-- = swap;
    }
}
```

Though the question is 3 ½ years old, chances are that someone else will be searching for the same thing. That's why I still post this.

Comment: The chance has realized :)

Comment: To complete the code, just add the casting: 


(unsigned char*)start + size - 1;

Answer (score 2):

If you need to reverse there is a chance that you can improve your algorithms and just use reverse iterators.

Comment: It's for reading data from files that uses different endiannesses.

Comment: @kitchen, this seems more like reversing the bytes of an integer, not the bytes of a whole array...

Answer (score 1):

If you're reversing binary data from a file with different endianness you should probably use the ntoh* and hton* functions, which convert specified data sizes from network to host order and vice versa. ntohl for instance converts a 32 bit unsigned long from big endian (network order) to host order (little endian on x86 machines).

Comment: This question concerns swapping an array, so the solutions provided above specifically answer than need.

Comment: Or see `endian.h` if you're using glib.

Answer (score 0):

I would review the stl::swap and make sure it's optimized; after that I'd say you're pretty optimal for space. I'm reasonably sure that's time-optimal as well.

Comment: Nowhere near time-optimal. The `size/2` calculation *might* be optimized out of being run every loop, but the `size-i-1` calculation wouldn't be, nor would the cost of the array indexing.

That said, a perfectly optimized loop wouldn't be *that* much faster than what he's got.