# Rotating video without rotating AVCaptureConnection and in the middle of AVAssetWriter session

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm using [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) to implement tap-to-record video functionality. The library doesn't support orientation yet so I'm in the process of trying to engineer it in. From what I see, there are three ways to rotate the video - I need help on deciding the best way forward and how to implement it. Note that rotation can happen between tap-to-record segments. So in a recording session, the orientation is locked to what it was when the user tapped the button. The next time the user taps the button to record, it should re-set the orientation to whatever the device's orientation is (so the resulting video shows right-side-up).

The approaches are outlined in the [issue page on GitHub as well](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision/issues/84)

**Method 1**
Rotate the `AVCaptureConnection` using `setVideoOrientation:` - this causes the video preview to flicker every time it's switched, since this switches the actual hardware it seems. Not cool, not acceptable.

**Method 2**
Set the `transform` property on the `AVAssetWriterInput` object used to write the video. The problem is, once the asset writer starts writing, the `transform` property can't be changed, so this only works for the first segment of the video.

**Method 3**
Rotate the image buffer being appended using something like this: [How to directly rotate CVImageBuffer image in IOS 4 without converting to UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528879/how-to-directly-rotate-cvimagebuffer-image-in-ios-4-without-converting-to-uiimag) but it keeps crashing and I'm not even sure if I'm barking up the right tree. There's an exception that is thrown and I can't really trace it back to much more than the fact that I'm using the `vImageRotate90_ARGB8888` function incorrectly.

The explanation is a bit more detailed on the GitHub issue page I linked to above. Any suggestions would be welcome - to be honest, I'm not hugely experienced at AVFoundation and so I'm hoping that there's some miraculous way to do this that I don't even know about!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 10):

Method 1 isn't the preferred method according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html) ("Physically rotating buffers does come with a performance cost, so only request rotation if it's necessary").  Method 2 worked for me but if I played my video on an app that doesn't support the transformation "metadata", the video isn't rotated properly.  Method 3 is what I did.

I think it's crashing for you before you're trying to pass the image data directly from `vImageRotate...` to the `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`.  You have to create a `CVPixelBufferRef` first.  Here's my code:

Inside of `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` I rotate the frame before writing it into the adaptor:

```
if ([self.videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
{
    // Rotate buffer first and then write to adaptor
    CMTime sampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferRef rotatedBuffer = [self correctBufferOrientation:sampleBuffer];
    [self.videoWriterInputAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:rotatedBuffer withPresentationTime:sampleTime];
    CVBufferRelease(rotatedBuffer);
}
```

The referenced function that performs the vImage rotation is:

```
/* rotationConstant:
 *  0 -- rotate 0 degrees (simply copy the data from src to dest)
 *  1 -- rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise
 *  2 -- rotate 180 degress
 *  3 -- rotate 270 degrees counterclockwise
 */

- (CVPixelBufferRef)rotateBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withConstant:(uint8_t)rotationConstant
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer        = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);        

    OSType pixelFormatType              = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer);
    NSAssert(pixelFormatType == kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, @"Code works only with 32ARGB format. Test/adapt for other formats!");

    const size_t kAlignment_32ARGB      = 32;
    const size_t kBytesPerPixel_32ARGB  = 4;

    size_t bytesPerRow                  = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width                        = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height                       = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    BOOL rotatePerpendicular            = (rotateDirection == 1) || (rotateDirection == 3); // Use enumeration values here
    const size_t outWidth               = rotatePerpendicular ? height : width;
    const size_t outHeight              = rotatePerpendicular ? width  : height;

    size_t bytesPerRowOut               = kBytesPerPixel_32ARGB * ceil(outWidth * 1.0 / kAlignment_32ARGB) * kAlignment_32ARGB;

    const size_t dstSize                = bytesPerRowOut * outHeight * sizeof(unsigned char);

    void *srcBuff                       = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    unsigned char *dstBuff              = (unsigned char *)malloc(dstSize);

    vImage_Buffer inbuff                = {srcBuff, height, width, bytesPerRow};
    vImage_Buffer outbuff               = {dstBuff, outHeight, outWidth, bytesPerRowOut};

    uint8_t bgColor[4]                  = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    vImage_Error err                    = vImageRotate90_ARGB8888(&inbuff, &outbuff, rotationConstant, bgColor, 0);
    if (err != kvImageNoError) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld", err);
    }

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    CVPixelBufferRef rotatedBuffer      = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL,
                                 outWidth,
                                 outHeight,
                                 pixelFormatType,
                                 outbuff.data,
                                 bytesPerRowOut,
                                 freePixelBufferDataAfterRelease,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                 &rotatedBuffer);

    return rotatedBuffer;
}

void freePixelBufferDataAfterRelease(void *releaseRefCon, const void *baseAddress)
{
    // Free the memory we malloced for the vImage rotation
    free((void *)baseAddress);
}
```

Note: You may like to use enumeration for `rotationConstant`. Something like that (don't call this function with `MOVRotateDirectionUnknown`):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(uint8_t, MOVRotateDirection)
{
    MOVRotateDirectionNone = 0,
    MOVRotateDirectionCounterclockwise90,
    MOVRotateDirectionCounterclockwise180,
    MOVRotateDirectionCounterclockwise270,
    MOVRotateDirectionUnknown
};
```

Note: If you need `IOSurface` support, you should use `CVPixelBufferCreate` instead of `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` and pass bytes data into it directly:

```
NSDictionary *pixelBufferAttributes = @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : @{} };
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                    outWidth,
                    outHeight,
                    pixelFormatType,
                    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(pixelBufferAttributes),
                    &rotatedBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(rotatedBuffer, 0);
uint8_t *dest = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(rotatedBuffer);
memcpy(dest, outbuff.data, bytesPerRowOut * outHeight);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(rotatedBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: This looks awesome, will give it a try and let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Warning: this method works fine for portrait, but not for landscape videos. If you wanna rotate a landscape video (using either  `rotationConstant` 0 or 2) you need to swap `width` and `height` in `bytesPerRowOut`, `outbuff` and `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`.

Comment: @JaiGovindani Did you understand where to write it?

Comment: No the project went cold, sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy and safe way.

```
#define degreeToRadian(x) (Double.pi * x / 180.0)

self.assetWriterInputVideo.transform = 
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(degreeToRadian(-90))) ;
```

Comment: from the question: "The problem is, once the asset writer starts writing, the transform property can't be changed"

Comment: no, this `transform` is only for display, it dose not really change the video data

Answer (score 1):

method 3 does work to rotate the frame of video。
But I found out it can cause the MM leak. in order to it, I try to move the funcation in the same thread as the merging the frame of video.
it does work.
When you meet the issue, Please take care.